Add all queries on logs to allow list in NextDNS
I'm planning to have my configuration set to by default block all TLDs and whitelist a handful of sites and only be able to access those. Since I use a lot of sites, and I don't want any interference, I used the device that is connected to my profile for about an hour or two, making sure to open all the sites and apps that I regularly use, and use all the features therein, in order to find what to put on the allowlist.
Now there are thousands of domains on the log, and I can't find the "allow all" button. How do I highlight every log made on a particular device and put them all on the allowlist? To add them one by one is obviously unnecessary -- right?

I ended up using a Python script that does this for me, but I would have liked an in-app feature.
